# Want to create an automation that switches between two tabs

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, browser-automation

I am new to automation and want to create an automation test which can do following:

Open one tab --- click and get some info from that tab

Switch to another tab --- click and get some info from this tab now.

Compare the infos.

We use Page Object Model to get info from one page. However the moment, I switch to another tab -- it switches the tab successfully but does not locate any element on it.

Any idea ?

Comment: May be element that you are locating is in-side the frame/iframe in new page (tab) opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions I would ask is,

1. Is the element locator correct?
2. Is this a *unique* element locator?
3. Is this a synchronization issue? Are you waiting enough for the page to load before finding the element?
4. Is this problem particular to a browser? Is it consistent across?

Also make sure you pass on the driver object from one page object to the other. Like,

```
public class PageOne {
  public PageOne(WebDriver driver) {
    //do something in constructor
  }
  public void someMethodInPage1() {
      driver.findElement(By.id("button1")).click();
      PageTwo pageTwo = new PageTwo(driver);
      pageTwo.someMethodInPage2();
    }
}

public class PageTwo {
  private WebDriver driver;
  public PageTwo(WebDriver driver) {
    //do something in constructor
    this.driver = driver;
  }
 public void someMethodInPage2() {
      driver.findElement(By.id("button2")).click();
    }
}
```